# Desktop items vanishing

Tags: windows-7, desktop, icons

The problem I am having is with my desktop items. Just to confirm, I have already:

1. Right clicked and selected "View" :- The box is checked.
2. I have tried showing hidden and system files, - no joy. Although I do have two .txt files called "desktop", if that helps at all.
3. I have checked in `C:\Users\AccountName\Desktop`: This folder is empty - However if I place an icon in there then it does show up on the desktop.
4. I have gone to **My Computer** and clicked the **Desktop** tab on the left hand side, the standard icons (Recycle Bin etc..) are displayed here (minus a few non standard ones of my own).

---

So my question is:

Why can I not see these icons when the computer clearly knows they are there? Furthermore, if I drag and drop them over to the `C\Users\...\Desktop` folder they all appear as shortcuts. I know this might sound OK, but I want to know why it wont work properly (and how to make it behave).

Comment: I found the registry keys keys responsible for this, they are located here: 
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
HideDesktopIcons\ClassicStartMenu]

and Here:

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\
HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]

Setting them to a value of zero will show the icon.

Comment: As to how they got changed, I saw somewhere else on this site that the windows task scheduler was to blame and to disable it. Any further info would be good. 

It should be noted that as I right this I found another setting by right clicking and hitting personalise, then checking/unchecking the desktop icons. 

Still no sign of my missing personal ones though..